# Get activerecord related field value when field is an expression in yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I am extending an attributeBehavior that concats some attributes and stores them in another one. The code works fine when the attributes to be concatenated or not in relations. But when I want to use an attribute like "relatedtable.field", there is no way to tell AR to get the value of that related field:

This is my ConcatAttributesBehavior:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;

class ConcatAttributesBehavior extends \yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior
{
    public $source_attributes = [];
    public $separator = ", ";

    protected function getValue($event)
    {
    $ret = '';
    foreach( $this->source_attributes as $attribute ) {
        if( $ret != '' ) {
            $ret .= $this->separator;
        }
        $ret .= strval($this->owner->$attribute); (*) 
    }
    return $ret;
    }
}
```

When I attach one of these behaviors to my model:

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [ 
           'concat' => [
            'class' => \app\components\ConcatAttributesBehavior::class,
            'attributes' => [
                self::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['name'],
                self::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['name'],
            ],
            'source_attributes' => [ 'person.name', 'school.name', 'date' ]
        ];
    }
```

I get the error:

```
  [yii\base\UnknownPropertyException] Getting unknown property: app\models\Student::person.name
```

The same if I look for `person->name`.

The problem is in the line marked with (*)

```
$ret .= strval($this->owner->$attribute);
```

I have tried all these variants:

```
$ret .= strval($this->owner->__get($attribute));
$ret .= strval($this->owner->getAtribute($attribute);
```

but none of them work.

The solution should include setting more than one relationship, like:

```
'person->school->address->country'
```

P.S 1) My model works perfectly if I try:

```
$student = Student::findOne(1);
echo $student->person->name;
```

P.S 2) The code I am missing inside AR __get would be similar to the one in BaseActiveRecord::getAttibuteHint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`ArrayHelper::getValue()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#getValue()-detail):

```
$ret .= strval(ArrayHelper::getValue($this->owner, $attribute));
```